# How to change the the coordinates of a C section as per variable in Python

Tags: python, abaqus

I am making a python script for my Abaqus model. For this I have to change the coordinates of the C section as per declared variable (thickness,length,height). But I don't know how can I change the coordinates.

```
###variables
l1 = [200.0 , 300.0] #length of lower flange
l2 = [200.0 , 300.0] #length of upper flange
t1 = [40.0 , 45.0]   #thickness of lower flange
t2 = [40.0 , 45.0]   #thickness of upper flange
height = [1000.0 , 1050.0 ] #total height of C section

for i in range(len(l1)):

    mdb.Model(name='Model-%s'%(i+1), modelType=STANDARD_EXPLICIT)
    session.viewports['Viewport: 1'].setValues(displayedObject=None)   
        
    s = mdb.models['Model-%s'%(i+1)].ConstrainedSketch(name='__profile__', 
        sheetSize=200.0)
    g, v, d, c = s.geometry, s.vertices, s.dimensions, s.constraints
    s.setPrimaryObject(option=STANDALONE)
        
    s = mdb.models['Model-%s'%(i+1)].ConstrainedSketch(name='__profile__', 
        sheetSize=200.0)
    g, v, d, c = s.geometry, s.vertices, s.dimensions, s.constraints
    s.setPrimaryObject(option=STANDALONE)
    
# Creating The C section 
    
    s.Line(point1=(0.0, 0.0), point2=(200.0, 0.0))     #How to change this coordinates as it can access the array
    s.HorizontalConstraint(entity=g[2], addUndoState=False)
    s.Line(point1=(200.0, 0.0), point2=(200.0, 40.0))  # What to write in the coordinates 
    s.VerticalConstraint(entity=g[3], addUndoState=False)
    s.PerpendicularConstraint(entity1=g[2], entity2=g[3], addUndoState=False)
    s.Line(point1=(200.0, 40.0), point2=(7.0, 40.0))   #
    s.HorizontalConstraint(entity=g[4], addUndoState=False)
    s.PerpendicularConstraint(entity1=g[3], entity2=g[4], addUndoState=False)
    s.Line(point1=(7.0, 40.0), point2=(7.0, 960.0))    #
    s.VerticalConstraint(entity=g[5], addUndoState=False)
    s.PerpendicularConstraint(entity1=g[4], entity2=g[5], addUndoState=False)
    s.Line(point1=(7.0, 960.0), point2=(200.0, 960.0))  #
    s.HorizontalConstraint(entity=g[6], addUndoState=False)
    s.PerpendicularConstraint(entity1=g[5], entity2=g[6], addUndoState=False)
    s.Line(point1=(200.0, 960.0), point2=(200.0, 1000.0)) #
    s.VerticalConstraint(entity=g[7], addUndoState=False)
    s.PerpendicularConstraint(entity1=g[6], entity2=g[7], addUndoState=False)
    s.Line(point1=(200.0, 1000.0), point2=(0.0, 1000.0))  #
    s.HorizontalConstraint(entity=g[8], addUndoState=False)
    s.PerpendicularConstraint(entity1=g[7], entity2=g[8], addUndoState=False)
    s.Line(point1=(0.0, 1000.0), point2=(0.0, 0.0))       #
    s.VerticalConstraint(entity=g[9], addUndoState=False)
    s.PerpendicularConstraint(entity1=g[8], entity2=g[9], addUndoState=False)
```

Comment: You are going to have to be much more specific about what you want - is your section uniform or is it varying along its length? It sounds more like a geometric problem than coding... You can access the list by l1[0] and l1[1] for instance. But if its varying, then you are going to have to change it into a piecewise linear form (i.e. function of length) for extending along the length of the section.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [how-to-ask-a -good-question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how-to-create-minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). After please show: 1) what you are doing; 2) what you are getting; 3) what doesn't work; 4) what is expected behaviour; 5) what have you tried to resolve the encountered problem? At the moment question is lacking information (as previouslly stated) and seems to be not Abaqus related  (more just python-specific)